# How to Open a File From FTP Directly In Text Editor / Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, mac, filesystems, ftp, visual-studio

It used to be that when I right-clicked on an `.html` file in FTP and selected `view/edit`:

[image]

it would automatically open the file in my text editor (Visual Studio Code).

Now it opens directly in the browser:

[image]

How can I make it so that when I right click on a file in FTP and select View / Edit, it will automatically open in VSCode?

Thank you!

Comment: you wrote " right-clicked on an .html file in FTP " <-- what does that mean? What program are you referring to.  And what is that image from, what program, what OS?!

Comment: I tried to show what that meant in the screenshot. This is a screenshot of what it looks like when you right-click on a file in FileZilla. I'm using a Mac OS Mojave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on an `.html` file on your desktop and select `Get Info`. Then select your text editor or `Visual Studio Code` from the "opens with" drop-down menu. Then hit change all.

[image]

**EDIT**: Be sure to stop and restart your Browser, Filezilla / FTP program, and Visual Studio Code / text editor after doing this.

**EDIT 2**: Just doing the above sometimes isn't enough. You may also have to change your file settings in FileZilla. Go to FileZilla --> Settings --> Filetype Associations, and make sure all of the filetypes you want to open in VS Code are entered in the text-area:

[image]

Comment: is this all on a mac? are these iimages mac specific? if so perhaps you should tag it osx

Comment: Yes - "macos" and "mac" tags added