# Make VSCode Default Editor For Files In FileZilla

Tags: ftp, html, javascript, filezilla, css

A very frustrating issue that I've tried to fix many times.

I'm trying to open a file from FileZilla directly in VSCode, so that when I save the file in Code, the changes are automatically updated via FTP.

Saving the file to a folder on the desktop, then uploading that file to FileZilla will work also, but if I can edit the files directly, it will save a step.

Right now, when I right-click on a file in FileZilla and select View / Edit, it opens the file in TextEdit (I'm on a Mac):

[image]

[image]

I've right-clicked on the .html file on my desktop and gone to 'get info', where VS Code is set as the default to open with.

So, why is FileZilla opening the files in TextEdit?

[image]

I'm not sure what else to try here.

This is happening with all file types - html, css, javascript, php, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I had already [asked and answered](https://superuser.com/questions/1407533/how-to-open-a-file-from-ftp-directly-in-text-editor-visual-studio-code) this question before.

But this time, the files were opening in TextEdit instead of in the browser.

I just did the same thing as before --> Right clicked on the file from the desktop, clicked on 'get info', selected VS Code under open with, and then selected 'Change All'.

It has worked for PHP files but still isn't working for HTML, CSS, or JavaScript.

I don't understand why not. I may have to delete TextEdit from the system and start over. I'm using macOS Catalina version 10.15.7.

**EDIT**: You have to go to Filezilla --> Settings --> Filetype Associations, and make sure that all of the necessary filetypes are associated with VS Code:

[image]